# Delete allocated memory in a STL map in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

i am using a map to store an pair (int and class) using the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class abstractclass{...};

class derivedclass : public abstractclass{...};

typedef map<int,abstractclass*> dBase;

int main(){
    dBase db;
    db.insert(pair<int,abstractclass*>(123,new derivedclass));
    db.insert(pair<int,abstractclass*>(124,new derivedclass));
}
```

How do i then delete the memory allocated to this?
I need to be able to use `insert` a user defined amount of times so a method that can delete every database entry is preferred, thanks!

If theres a way i can do this without using memory allocation that would also be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your `abstractclass` has a virtual destructor, you can simply iterate over all the items in the container and `delete` the `second` component of the item to free the memory. There are multiple ways of doing this: For example for loop, or `for_each` with a functor or lambda.

EDIT:
Upon further review, it appears that the map has ownership here, and your life will be *much* easier if you either use  a `map` of `shared_ptr` (from boost or C++11), or use a `boost::ptr_map` instead. Then you don't have to worry about cleaning up the map at all - you can just use `db.clear();` and all the items will be cleaned up automatically. Either of these containers would also help with managing memory in the face of inserting duplicate items.

Comment: So would this work:
`for(dbIT = db.begin(); dbIT != db.end();++dbIT){
  delete dbIT->second;
 }` where dbIT is `dBase::iterator dbIT`

Comment: is there a neat way to delete a duplicate entry on insert call?

Comment: @10WaRRioR01: no, you have to take care of that yourself, which can quickly turn into a headache (`insert` can throw so you need to write exception-safe code that will delete your `new`'ed object only if the insertion failed, either a smart pointer or a `try/catch`, it complicates the code quite a lot).

Comment: @clairharrison: Yes this is the idea. However, avoiding memory leaks is not just a matter of deleting the objects in the map at the end of the program, there are lots of other places you need to take care of and you need to be really careful about that.

Comment: I would prefer std::unique_ptr to std::shared_ptr unless the objects really do have shared ownership.

Answer (score 11):

Due to your class hierarchy you obviously can't just store your `abstractclass` objects by value in the `map` or you'd run into [the infamous object slicing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).

The usual way to solve this problem is to use smart pointers, eg. `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` (both C++11, for C++03 *never use* `std::auto_ptr` in containers since it is broken, but you can safely use the `boost` smart pointers instead).

So your `map` type would become eg. `std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<abstractclass>>`.
Then you don't need to bother any more about deleting the objects, when they are removed from the map the smart pointer will automatically take care of it.

Another solution is to `delete` all the items yourself (like @MarkB said) but this is very error prone so smart pointers are usually preferred when possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a smart pointer in your container:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class abstractclass{...};

class derivedclass : public abstractclass{...};

typedef map<int,shared_ptr<abstractclass>> dBase;

int main(){
    dBase db;
    shared_ptr<abstractclass> ptr1(new derivedclass);
    shared_ptr<abstractclass> ptr2(new derivedclass);
    db.insert(pair<int,shared_ptr<abstractclass>>(123,ptr1));
    db.insert(pair<int,shared_ptr<abstractclass>>(124,ptr2));
}
```

The shared pointers will give a little bit of overhead here, but the advantages are:

1. You don't have to care about deleting your objects - they will get deleted as soon as the map is destroyed.
2. You can safely create a new object and try to insert it into the map - if the insertion fails (even with exception), the allocated object will be safely destroyed.
3. You can insert an empty pointer and reset() it later with an actually created value (i.e. to not actually create an object, if a value with such key already exists)

Comment: Thanks, ill use that in future, i need to prove i know how to delete allocated memory for this project though but your method will be more use in the long run

Comment: Well, if you explain to whoever checks your project how and why you use smart pointers, that'd give you even more points :)